# Copying state of hundreds of standalone git repositories

Tags: git

I am going to solve this problem if is not already solved.

I have many huge projects. Some of them are repo-based like AOSP. Some projects uses git submodules. And a lot of standalone or additional  repositories with customizations from 3rd parties.

This horde is build successfully, pushed and committed on one host.

Tasks, which need to solve automatically:

1. collect all git repositories state information: dirs, urls, branches, hashes.
2. Copy/sync the state to another host.
3. Perform all needed operations:

   - git clone --branch ... for new modules
   - update to specified branches and hashes for existed modules

Theoretically it is possible to create and manage manually additional repo and git submodules, but it requires too much of manual work.

**EDIT**: OP said they would like to post their own answer here. Please vote to reopen to give them a chance to do so, and let them provide valuable information to the SO community.

Comment: Try to solve one problem after another. You could use a Shell script i guess, but then it must be clear what exactly you have and what you need.

Comment: This is a pretty significant task you're asking for, probably days or weeks of work, and unfortunately no one here (or no one anywhere) will do it unless you pay them. As you work on it, come back here if you have specific programming or technical questions along the way: we'll be happy to help with those.

Comment: @joanis, I have some ideas and I am going to do it and post my results here. Can you please up vote the question and ask to release the hold?

Comment: @Christoph, than you for your suggestion. I afraid this task should be solved as whole because there no much sense in partial tasks. For example it is trivial to traverse tree, find repositories and dump status:

find -name .git -printf "%h " -execdir git describe --always \;

Now need to collect more info and a way to restore it.

Comment: @Costa OK, I'll give it a try and vote to reopen it, but I might not get traction as I'm just one reviewer and the question is indeed very broad.

Comment: A comment for the reopen vote queue: please consider voting to reopen, to give a chance to OP to post their answer. I believe that if they provide a good answer to this problem themselves, it will be valuable to the rest of the developer community and be relevant to this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More advanced solution.
150+ sloc of python script:
https://github.com/makelinux/gitm/
The script scans tree of gits and stores status in a json file. Then the script compares another location with the status and synchronizes it.
When a repository is absent it performs "clone" and when it is present but not synchronized - "checkout".

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution. This bash function generates "git clone" script which regenerates local git structure:

```
git-tree-clone()
{
        find \( -name .git -printf "%h\n" \) | \
                while read dir; do
                        pushd $dir > /dev/null
                        remote=($(git remote -v))
                        echo "git clone ${remote[1]} $dir;" \
                              "git -C $dir checkout $(git describe --always)"
                        popd > /dev/null
                done
}
```

Limitations: skips branch name, remote name, can't update.